# Python 3.4 + Django 1.8 and XAMPP 3.2 on Windows 8.1 (64bit)

Tags: python, django, apache, xampp

just jumped on django, followed an installation guide from https://docs.djangoproject.com/ according to it all worked, when I typed 127.0.0.1:8000 i could see the message.

Found a simple Hello World app that should have showed a message when I access 
localhost/mysite/myapp.py But instead I can see the actual code.

My problem is when I want to use the xampp server, in order to be able to simulate actual website project. Found sources which suggest that I have to install mod_wsgi. What I did was copying the mod_wsgi into the appache module folder and tried to configure it on the httpd config file. When I type there

```
 LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
 WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts/test.wsgi"
 AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts">
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

the appache doesnt even start.

```
16:35:20  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
16:35:20  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
16:35:21  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
16:35:21  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
```

Thank you !

Comment: Where did you get mod_wsgi binary from? Did you read https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst and use binaries referenced from there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I've spent some time preparing all the things and accordingly to your answer everything should be the same. Python 3.4 with apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi_4.. all VC10 compiled. Still I encounter the same problem. Appache doesn't want to start.

Comment: Is there anything specific about the XAMPP Apache distribution you need, or could you use the one the mod_wsgi binaries are compiled against. I don't know whether problems can arise from using the different Apache distribution.